# Ionic serve: The provided value contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack

I am trying to run the following simple startup command for Ionic:

```
ionic serve
```

This should start a development server that serves me my project but it raises the following error instead:

```
> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=810
[ng] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
[ng]  - configuration.context: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]    -> The base directory (absolute path!) for resolving the `entry` option. If `output.pathinfo` is set, the included pathinfo is shortened to this directory.
[ng]  - configuration.module.rules[13].include should be one of these:
[ng]    RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? } | [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
[ng]    -> One or multiple rule conditions
[ng]    Details:
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[10].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[10].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[10].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[10].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[11].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[11].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[11].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[11].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[12].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[12].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[12].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[12].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[13].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[13].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[13].include[0]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\theme\\variables.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]     * configuration.module.rules[13].include[1]: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\src\\global.scss" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]  - configuration.output.path: The provided value "C:\\Users\\anton\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Documentos!\\ionic\\03-componentes\\www" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
[ng]    -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
[ng] See "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-AnavB0\angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Could somebody tell me what this error means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output log clearly states

> The provided value "C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Documentos!\ionic\03-componentes\www" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed.

Remove the `!` in your folder `Documentos!`